# Options for Web application frameworks using elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What are the options of web application frameworks for elixir laguagem? Recently I was studying Phoenix (http://phoenixframework.org/) but I'm not sure if is the best or the only option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me this is too much general question to ask and it would be better for you to get valid response on Elixir Slack on Elixir Forum, rather then here.

This is the [list of known frameworks](https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#frameworks) for Elixir.

Why choose Phoenix?

- members of Elixir core team are members of Phoenix core team
- it's most mature of all of Elixir web frameworks
- it's most contributed Elixir web framework
- it's most popular Elixir web framework
- you have the best resources for Phoenix - books, tutorials, videocasts and documentation

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow hates opinion questions; That said, I love using `Plug` in Elixir to serve content, and writing the UI using `React`, esp. using [create_react_app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).